# How to keep value of req.session in express-session

Tags: javascript, session, express, express-session

I have the following codes:

```
var session = require('express-session');
var sessionConfig = {
   secret: 'somesecretkey', 
   cookie: {secure: false}, 
   resave: false, 
   saveUninitialized: false, 
   store: new mongostore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection })
}

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  var abc = req.session.user;
  var trueOrFalse = isset(abc);

  console.log(trueOrFalse);
  req.session.user = 1;
  req.session.save();
});

function isset(var1){
  if( typeof var1 !== 'undefined' ) {
     return true;
}
  return false;
}
```

My expectation response is print 'false' for the first time, then after I refresh the page, it will always print 'true' for the following times. However, it always prints 'false' as it didn't keep the value.

Please help.

Comment: what do you get in console if you output `req.session.user` in both the situations i.e. first load and subsequent loads?

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj I always get undefined value for req.session.user no matter how many times I reload the page.

Comment: Are you sure your `mongoose.connection` works fine? Can you check that there is a `sessions` collection in your connected database?

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj Yes I'm sure the mongoose.connection is fine. The issue here is whenever I reload the page, the session I created has reset.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but it seems you have not added the session as middleware so that all incoming requests pass through this. You can probably do it something like this (in your main file usually `app.js`):

```
var session = require('express-session');
app.use(session({
   secret: 'somesecretkey', 
   cookie: {secure: false}, 
   resave: false, 
   saveUninitialized: false, 
   store: new mongostore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection })
}));

// Now here come your route handlers
app.use("/", routes);
```